# Blazor Navigation: Update URL without changing reloading page

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I use URL parameters for page state in my app.

How can i change the URL without actually navigating?

Thanks!

(using blazor server side)

Comment: Is using js interop ok?

Comment: Sure, but could you include how to use JavaScript interop?

Comment: Can you elaborate your Q with code sample?

Comment: give us code sample or scenario

Comment: Isn't there a way to not use the js nor NavigateTo to update the Url yet?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do this with JS Interop and call `history.pushState(null, '', url)`

Here is a simple example

**.razor**

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

<input
    @bind="url"
/>

<button @onclick="ChangeUrl">
    Change Url
</button>

<p>@url</p>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    void ChangeUrl(){
        // You can also change it to any url you want
        jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("ChangeUrl", Url);
    }
}
```

**.js**

```
window.ChangeUrl = function(url){
    history.pushState(null, '', url);   
}
```

**Please notice** that this only works for visual purpose, it will only change for the browser while in the server side, you probably won't see the change.

Comment: Would it get more correct if it use `jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("ChangeUrl", Url);` on this case,as the function does not return anything?

Comment: Take in account that, after changing URL with JS, when user hit "Back" button in a browser, the browser will change URL back but application state will not change.

I recommend using the `NavigationManager.NavigateTo` method. It will not reload the page if it is not necessary (or not called with `forceReload` flag). Then history will be handled properly and `NavigationManager.LocationChanged` event will be fired.

Answer (score 19):

If you just want to add/remove/change query parameters in the URL, use the `NavigationManager.NavigateTo` method. It will not reload the page if it is not necessary (or not called with `forceReload` flag).

For example, the current URL is `"https://example.com/page"`, then call `NavigationManager.NavigateTo("https://example.com/page?id=1")` will not reload the page but only modify URL. Click "Back" in browser will change the URL to `"https://example.com/page"`, this change can be handled with `NavigationManager.LocationChanged` event.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.navigationmanager.navigateto

Comment: The "problem" in this scenario with `NavigateTo` is that it would actually navigate, and initialize the page/component matching that route again, which, as I understand it, the OP are looking to avoid.

Comment: I don't think that is true. The navigation manager NavigateTo performs client-side routing and only makes server calls when it is not a client-side route. My blazor app reads in query parameters then uses NavigateTo to clear the params from the Uri. This doesn't reload my blazor app.

Comment: Technically speaking, this is the right solution. The JS interop solution seems like a hack to me. Tested in Blazor .NET7, works perfectly and does not reload the page if it is not needed. Full URL not needed, something like this also works ```navigationManager.NavigateTo("/counter/50");```

Comment: A practical tip: Since .NET 6 you can use the extension method [`NavigationManager#GetUriWithQueryParameters()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.navigationmanagerextensions.geturiwithqueryparameters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-components-navigationmanagerextensions-geturiwithqueryparameters(microsoft-aspnetcore-components-navigationmanager-system-collections-generic-ireadonlydictionary((system-string-system-object)))) to create a URL based on the current URL with the required parameters set accoring to the values within the dictionary.

Comment: @Michel Jansson is right, I just had even a case like this in .net 8, it does reinitilize the component, even when you call `navigateTo(..., forceLoad: false)`

Comment: I was wrong or something changed when I went from .net6 to .net7. I'm having the issue of component re-initialization using navigateTo when it should just be doing a history.pushState. It does work to use JS to change the URL, but then NavigationManager is out of sync. Has anyone found a way to update NavigationManager after the JS history.pushState has been executed?