# How Blazor can navigate to different http path in browser address bar without any server interaction?

Tags: blazor

I am new to Blazor and I am noticing that my starter application can navigate to a http path without any http GET interaction with the web server as shown below:

[image]

The counter hyper link is actually an anchor tag:

[image]

But there is a Blazor magic that allows the user navigate to different URLs without any browser's HTTP get  interaction with the web server.

How Blazor can do that? What is the name of this JavaScript technique so I can search for it and learn it?

Comment: Read up about Single Page Applications - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis, I did. Still I don't know the name of JavaScript or DOM technique that change the Browser's address bar. I am a developer, like to see the code. All I need is the name of the technique/pattern/feature that allows my JavaScript code  changes the Address bar's urls.

Comment: Here's an article that provides some detail - https://chrissainty.com/an-in-depth-look-at-routing-in-blazor/.  If you want the real detail you need to access the DotNetCore Github repository - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/ - and start digging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the DOM (Document Object Model) manipulation.

Blazor is a SPA (Single Page Application), this mean the DOM (the page HTML structure) is generated by Blazor.

You can force page reload with the NavigationManager.

More infos here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Thank you for help and this makes sense. Do you know a sample JavaScript call that manipulates the url that shown on browser's addressbar?

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60494746/blazor-navigation-update-url-without-changing-reloading-page